# Add Google Analytics to framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, google-analytics

I try to put the AnalyticsManager of few my app targets to my embedded framework for sharing it functional. But after moving my Swift files and the pod of Google Analytics to framework target I have an issue: in a framework I can't use bridging file for adding Objective-C headers. 
Apple say in their documentation: [..In your umbrella header file, import every Objective-C header you want to expose to Swift...](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Ok, I have created my **public** *projectName-Swift.h* file with `#import <Google/Analytics.h>`
  and wrote it path to the Search Headers Path row in the Build Settings.
And happens nothing. In my AnalyticsManager I still see the warning about GAI unresolved identifier.

btw I set import Google in the top of the AnalyticsManager file, and the GGLContext object is referenced and not have a warning.Furthermore
my framework have many pods such as Alamofire, MagicalRecords, CocoaLumberjack, SwiftyJSON, etc and everything works fine except the GA pod.
Thanks.

Comment: are you using use_frameworks! in your Podfile by chance? If so you don't need any header related work. The import for google analytics in swift is "import Google.Analytics"

Comment: of course I use use_frameworks!. Google.Analitics, Google.Core and  Google.SignIn reverenced by  'import Google' but no result